# Ansible to get the netmask in CIDR

Tags: ansible, jinja2

In order to get the value "24" corresponding to an IP address/networkmask, I have this working piece of code:

```
- set_fact:
    ip: "{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}/{{ansible_default_ipv4.netmask }}"

- set_fact:
    mask_cidr: "{{ ip | ipaddr('prefix') }}"
```

Where `ansible_default_ipv4.address` = `172.16.1.67` and `ansible_default_ipv4.netmask` is `255.255.255.0` as per `gather_facts` or `setup` module.

I've tried different things to make this code "smarter" so I only need to set 1 fact instead of 2, but my filtering abilities are not strong.

Any ideas in how to convert these two facts in a smarter fact that do both things?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easiest and the most clean way is through a helper variable:

```
- set_fact:
    mask_cidr: "{{ ip | ipaddr('prefix') }}"
  vars:
    ip: "{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}/{{ansible_default_ipv4.netmask }}"
```

If you insist on writing a single template:

```
- sef_fact:
    ip: "{{ (ansible_default_ipv4.address + '/' + ansible_default_ipv4.netmask) | ipaddr('prefix') }}"
```

Comment: :) Well...I thought I was going to learn 1 new thing, but I ended up learning 2 things! I did not know about the "vars" option under set_fact :D
Thank you very much!

Comment: You can add `vars` to any task, it is not "under", it is on the same level as `set_fact`.

Comment: The oneliner is not working as expected tho. The reason for wanting this in a "oneliner" is because i'm trying to set this on a variable file. With this filter I'm getting a netmask of value 32 instead of the 24 expeted. The only way I found to make it return "24" is by providing an input of ip_add/netmask. By applying the filter only in ansible_default_ipv4.netmask, it returns 32 (original problem). This is the line i'm trying:
zimbraMtaMyNetworks="127.0.0.0/8 {{ ansible_default_ipv4.network | string + '/' + ansible_default_ipv4.netmask | ipaddr('prefix') | string }}"
Any ideas?

Comment: Pay attention to parentheses.

Comment: Yeap :) Thank you!!! :))) It is working as expected now.
zimbraMtaMyNetworks="127.0.0.0/8 {{ ansible_default_ipv4.network }}/{{ (ansible_default_ipv4.network + '/' + ansible_default_ipv4.netmask) | ipaddr('prefix') | string }}"
-> zimbraMtaMyNetworks="127.0.0.0/8 172.16.1.0/24"

Answer (score 8):

I'm using this:

```
mynetwork = {{ (ansible_default_ipv4.network + '/' + ansible_default_ipv4.netmask) | ipaddr('network/prefix') }}
```

Comment: `ipaddr('network/prefix')` can be more concisely expressed as `ipaddr('net')`.